# SQL query to join to the same parent table twice

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables in my db:

Table 
Flights:

```
ID
ID_Destination
ID_Source
```

Table Locations:

```
ID (that relatesto the id of source and destination)
Name
Country
Etc..
```

Now I need a query that gives me the information of all flights from a certain source to certain destination. I have tried long in the query editor but inner join does not work here. What should I use instead?

I would need as a result something like:

```
1st flight: Naples Italy |London England
2nd flight: Rome Italy | Mailand Italy
etc..
```

Comment: What was the inner join query you tried that did not work?

Comment: Edit the question with some sample data and desired result.

Comment: Stop making people guess and read your mind. If you need help with sql you need to post the table definition, sample data and desired output. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next inner join should work here:

```
SELECT f.ID, CONCAT(sl.Name, ' ', sl.Country), CONCAT(dl.Name, ' ', dl.Country)
FROM Flights as f
INNER JOIN Locations as sl ON sl.ID = f.ID_Source
INNER JOIN Locations as dl ON dl.ID = f.ID_Destination
```

Function "CONCAT" is a part of MySql, so this function can not work for all databases, without it just:

```
SELECT f.ID, sl.Name, sl.Country, dl.Name, dl.Country
FROM Flights as f
INNER JOIN Locations as sl ON sl.ID = f.ID_Source
INNER JOIN Locations as dl ON dl.ID = f.ID_Destination
```

Comment: Aleksey I tried the one without concat and it gives me only one result, where there should be 3 (I have 3 records in the flights table)

Comment: I tried the one with concat and it also gives me only one result instead of three records

Comment: My problem were I was using misleading data. These both solutions worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the locations table twice:

```
SELECT 
   id, 
   source.name as `Source Name`, 
   source.country as `Source Country`, 
   destination.name as `Destination Name`, 
   destination.country as `Destination Country` 
FROM flights
JOIN locations source ON source.id = flights.source_id
JOIN locations destination ON destination.id = flights.destination_id
```

Comment: This also does not work. I get 1 record instead of 3

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `subquery`:

```
select id,
      (select top(1) concat(name, ' ', country) from locations where id = f.ID_Source) as Source,
      (select top(1) concat(name, ' ', country) from locations where id = f.ID_Destination) as Destination, 
from flights f
group by id;
```

Comment: This also does not work. I get 1 record instead of 3.

Comment: @user1238784... Then edit the question with some sample data and desired result.